# Grepping with app.findGrepPreferences.appliedFont fails for Walkman-Chanakya-905 (TT)

Tags: adobe-indesign, indesign-scripting

I have InDesign JavaScript code that replaces strings of specific fonts. Tt works (mostly) including for appliedFont values containing spaces and dashes e.g. Walkman-Chanakya-905, Devlys 180 Thin:-

```
app.findGrepPreferences.appliedFont = srcFont; 
app.findGrepPreferences.fontStyle = srcStyle; 
app.findGrepPreferences.findWhat = findWhat;
app.changeGrepPreferences.appliedFont = tgtFont;
app.changeGrepPreferences.fontStyle = tgtStyle;
app.changeGrepPreferences.changeTo = changeTo;
```

But it fails only when appliedFont is set to this - **Walkman-Chanakya-905 (TT)**

However when I set the same font (and style) in the find dialog under the grep tab it works as expected.

[image]

It also works when I disable font matching so it is likely it has something to do with the font (name).

```
// disabling this works -> app.findGrepPreferences.appliedFont = srcFont; 
app.findGrepPreferences.fontStyle = srcStyle; 
app.findGrepPreferences.findWhat = findWhat;
app.changeGrepPreferences.appliedFont = tgtFont;
app.changeGrepPreferences.fontStyle = tgtStyle;
app.changeGrepPreferences.changeTo = changeTo;
```

What is happening?

Comment: Does it work with other fonts with brackets () on the name?

Comment: Thanks. I have no other fonts with a name that has brackets. I don't even have this font available but that should be fine as I don't have many others either.

Comment: when I use the "package" functionality on a file, I see a file created in the package folder with the "idml" extension. If you see this, it is a zip file, rename it to the "zip" extension, unzip it and look for a file called "fonts.xml" in one of the subfolders, check the indesign-internal name for the problem font to see if there is a naming discrepancy.

Comment: Yes let me check that and come back. Thanks.

Comment: You can check all the fonts in a document using `app.Document.fonts` iterate over this and print `font.fullName` to get the font's internal name